# WPF: Custom control that binds its content to a label

Tags: wpf-controls

I want to write a custom control that's used like this:

```
<HorizontalTick>Some string</HorizontalTick>
```

It should render like this:

-- Some string -------------------------------------------

Here's my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WeatherDownloadDisplay.View.HorizontalTick"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="348"
             Name="controlRoot">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <UserControl VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="10"/>
        <Label Content="???" />
        <UserControl VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

It works except for the label binding.  Can someone help me fill in the question marks?  I thought about using a ContentPresenter but it seems like an inline binding would be best.

-Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding would be:

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Content}" />
```

However, reconsider using a `ContentPresenter` to be able to show any content directly rather than adding a label that will use its own `ContentPresenter` to show it.

That being said, you could also replace your whole control by a simple `ContentControl` with a `ContentTemplate` showing the lines and the inner content.